# How do I create a slice of one item in Go?

Tags: go

Let's say a function takes a slice of strings:

```
func Join(strs []string) {
     ...
}
```

I have a single string:

```
a := "y'all ain't got the honey nut?"
```

How can I convert that string into a slice?

Comment: Note that `strs` is not an array but a slice.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can create a slice of one item using the following convention:

```
a := "y'all ain't got the honey nut?"
singleItemArray := []string{a}

strings.Join(singleItemArray);
```

Comment: That's a slice, not an array.

Answer (score 12):

The actual answer to your question is as simple as `[]string{"string"}`, as miltonb said.

But what I wanted to point out is how easy it is to write and use a variadic function in Go, a function with a variable number of arguments.

You can change signature of your function to `F(a ...string)`. Then, `a` is slice in the function `F`, and you can call it like `F("a")` and `F("a", "b")`. And when you actually have a slice or array, you can pass it to F by calling `F(a...)`.

Not sure if this syntax fits your job, but I wanted to let you know about it as an option.

Answer (score 2):

The question as phrased actually references Arrays and Slices.  The question text is about an array and the code is illustrating using a slice.  Therefore there two questions are implied; pass a single item slice, and pass a single item array.

An array:  `var a [1]string`
A slice: `var s []string`

Passing a **single item slice** to the function:

```
func SliceFunc( slc []string) {
    fmt.Println(slc)
}

func main() {
    a := "stringy"
    SliceFunc( []string{a} )
    // or an actual array to the same function
    b := [...]string { "thingy" }
    SliceFunc( []string{b[0] )  
}
```

Passing a **single item array** to the function.

Here there is an issue, as an array has a fixed length and as a parameter to a function it cannot accept different length arrays so we are left with working function which has limited flexibility:

```
func ArrayFunc( arr [1]string) {
    fmt.Println(slc)
}

func main() {
    var a [1]string
    a[0] = "stringy"
    ArrayFunc( a )  
}
```

It seems that as a generalization sticking to slices is a more flexible solution.

(If you would like more on Slices and Arrays here one blog by Andrew Gerrand covering [go slices usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).)

Comment: That's a slice, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `append` or `make`:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   {
      var a []string
      a = append(a, "north")
      fmt.Println(a)
   }
   {
      a := make([]string, 1)
      a[0] = "north"
      fmt.Println(a)
   }
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/builtin